# Unity - Main manifest has <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion='9'> but library uses minSdkVersion='17'

Tags: unity, android

I got this error message when trying to build and run for Android.

[image]

> Error: [Temp/StagingArea/AndroidManifest-main.xml:22,
>   /Users/MNurdin/Documents/unity/TangoMotion/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/google-unity-wrapper/AndroidManifest.xml:3]
>   Main manifest has  but library
>   uses minSdkVersion='17'
>   UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()

Where I can set `android:minSdkVersion` inside `Unity`? I'm using Unity5 right now. Please advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple spots that could be relevant. First off, you can set the Min API Level in Player Settings (click the Player Settings button on the bottom of that screenshot).

But besides that, you can manually provide your own manifest file; it looks like right now you are simply using the manifest that Unity automatically generates if you don't provide one manually. When an Android app is built, Unity puts the generated manifest file in the Temp folder at StagingArea/AndroidManifest.xml; copy that file to manually edit it. Provide one manually by putting it in Plugins/Android/ alongside the plug-in JAR.

Comment: hi can you please explain it in detail. i am also facing the same problem. I am completely new to the facebook connection system

Answer (score 0):

I have had trouble with this for days, but now my app works well. Doing like below, may help you.

Read [this section of the manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-gradle-overview.html),
then change `**TARGETSDKVERSION**` to your desired number in `mainTemplate.gradle`, such as 22, 23, etc.